# NServiceBus Simple Retry Mechanism, how do I debug (based on AsyncPages sample)

Tags: nservicebus

Hi
I have a website where a user signs up we need to add them to a legacy system via a soap webservice call. these webservice calls are queue'd for retry asynchronously...
I have copied the AsyncPages sample from the NServiceBus download.

However the messages seem to flit in and out of the queue without being handled (nor are they put on the error queue). (the message shows in the journal)

my website is configured like so:

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
        <add Messages="FooComMessages" Endpoint="FooComSignupService"/>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

And I have this test code on a button click:

```
Global.Bus.Send(new CreateMemberContractRequest[] 
                    {new CreateMemberContractRequest()
                        {birthdate = DateTime.Parse("4 oct 1975")}
                     }
                );
```

My message:

```
namespace FooComMessages
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CreateMemberContractRequest : IMessage
    {
        public DateTime birthdate { get; set; }
//.... snip....//
    }
}
```

My Handler Config:

```
  <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="FooComSignupService" ErrorQueue="FooComSignupServiceErrors" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="20" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="FooComMessages" Endpoint="FooComSignupService" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

My Handler Code:

```
namespace FooComSignupService
{
    public class CreateMemberContractRequestHandler : IHandleMessages<CreateMemberContractRequest>
    {
        public IBus Bus { get; set; }
        private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CreateMemberContractRequestHandler));
        public void Handle(CreateMemberContractRequest message)
        {
            Logger.Info("------------------------------------\nHandling CreateMemberContractRequest. id="+message.webdatabaseid);
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I'm using NServiceBus.Host.exe to host the FooComSignupService

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?
I can't hit any breakpoints in the Handle method either.

Cheers.
Murray.

Comment: I've also asked here: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/9415

Comment: What happens if you do: Global.Bus.Send(new CreateMemberContractRequest()
                        {birthdate = DateTime.Parse("4 oct 1975")}
                     
                ); ?

Comment: I see one or more items appear in this queue: Private Queues > FooComSignupService > Journal messages (and nothing anywhere else)

Comment: How are you hosting + configuring your FooComSignupService? Can you post the code here?

Comment: using NServiceBus.Host.exe (configuration & code already included)

Comment: Can you post your class that implements IConfigureThisEndpoint ?